# Review queue audit questions give themselves away by displaying inconsistent information

Tags: bug, review, review-audits

The questions used as "audit" questions in the review queues generally show modified values for these fields, which clearly helps to disguise the fact that they're actually high-ranked questions:

- answers
- accepted
- asked
- viewed

Today, however, I was delivered a review item with "answers **0**" and "accepted **yes**", which told me immediately it was a trap question!

Here's an example from stackoverflow:

[image: screenshot of inconsistent audit question]

Answer (score 4):

Congratulations! You passed.

The fact you noticed this is a clear indication the review audit worked. Review audits are meant to be obvious. If they are hard, one would easily fail.

Robo-reviewers don't take the time to go through the facts as you did. That will make them fail the audit.

Comment: In the sense that reviewing is a game, yes, it's a way of winning, but where the purpose of a review is to examine the _written content_ of the post, wouldn't you consider it a flaw in the game?